# Riesz-Type Representation Theorems for Convex Functionals

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

It is well known that any positive linear functional $L$ on the spase $C_c([a,b])$ of functions continuous on an interval $[a,b]$ with compact support can be written as 
\begin{align*}
L(x)=\int_a^bx(t)d\mu(t),\qquad x\in C_c([a,b]),
\end{align*}
where $\mu$ is some proper Radon-measure. The question for me now arises, if there are any similar results, if $L$ is only a convex functional. To be precise, my questions are

*(1) Let $X$ be a real vector space of measurable functions $[a,b]\to\mathbb R$, and let $L:X\to[0,\infty)$ be a convex functional. Does there exist a convex function $\varphi:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ and a Borel/Radon measure $\mu$ such that
\begin{align*}
    L(x)=\int_a^b\varphi(x(t))\mu(t),\qquad x\in X?
\end{align*}
(2) What conditions on $X$ and maybe on $L$ have to be added such that a representation of the aforementioned kind is possible?*

*(3) If equality cannot be achieved, is it possible to estimate $L$ from above and below by integrals like those in (1)?*

Any help is highly appreciated, and any literature recommendations are very welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Example for (1):** For $x\in C([a,b])$ and $\mu$ a positive finite measure on $[a,b]$, define $L(x)=\log\int_a^b \exp(x(t))\,d\mu(t)$. This $L$ is convex both not of the form you are hoping for.

Comment: Thank you! But $L$ is not positive, right? If $x$ is constant and "sufficiently negative", then $L(x)<0$.

Comment: No, this $L$ is not positive.  It wasn't apparent to me that positivity was implicit in "convex functional".

Comment: **Modified example:** $L(x)=\left(\log\int_a^b \exp(x(t))\,d\mu(t)\right)^+$.  (The $+$ superscript indicates positive part.) This functional is convex and positive.

Comment: Hm ok, but I don't see why this functional cannot be written in the desired form. Can you add some details pls? Thx!

Comment: Consider my example functional in the special case where $\mu$ is the sum of a unit mass at $a$ and a unit mass at $b$. If $L$ is to have the desired form then (take $x\in C([a,b])$ with $x(a)=x(b)=t$) we must have 
$$
\log(2e^t) =L(x) =2\varphi(t)
$$
for all real $t$, and then we would have
$$
\log[\exp(x(a))+\exp(x(b))]=\log 2+{x(a)+x(b)\over 2},
$$
for all $x\in C([a,b])$, which is clearly not the case.